# Communication between concurrent AWS Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-dynamodb

I want a set of concurrent *AWS Lambda* functions to write and read data from a common place. They will read the last post introduced and perhaps will write a new (last) post. Posts will be short - less than 1kB - and in *json* format. Once the last concurrent lambda will finish the execution, the posts will be deleted.

I am considering using *AWS Dynamo DB*. Do you think that this is the best option? Is it possible to use *AWS CloudWatch*?

Comment: DynamoDB seems like a good choice, I don't see how CloudWatch would help you.

Comment: Perfect use-case for ElasticCache!

Comment: This isn't really communication between concurrent Lambdas, it's shared persistent state. DynamoDB will be simpler and probably much cheaper than ElastiCache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely two options Dynamo & ElasticCache. Pretty basic answer, I am sure there are more things to consider, just focussing on this use case.

**Dynamo**

Pros: serverless

Cons:

- Probably need strongly consistent reads to fetch most recent update in sub milli second difference.
- Also could become expensive than ElasticCache depending on how many read/writes we are making.

**ElasticCache**

Pros: Faster than Dynamo, as it is in-memory.

Cors: we need to run a server, so, will be paying some min $.